# Agrupamento SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso fazer o seguinte select:

```
'SELECT TR.CODPARC, TR.NOMEPARC, TB.CODVEND, TV.APELIDO, TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP, TP.AD_CAMPLENTE, TP.AD_CAMPPONTOS
FROM TGFCAB TB, TGFITE TE, TGFPRO TP, TGFPAR TR, TGFVEN TV
Where Tb.Nunota = Te.Nunota 
AND TB.CODVEND = TV.CODVEND
AND TP.CODPROD = TE.CODPROD
AND TB.CODPARC = TR.CODPARC
And Tb.Tipmov = 'P'
AND TB.CODTIPOPER IN (3100, 3102, 3105)
AND TB.DTNEG >= :PERIODO.INI
AND TB.DTNEG <= :PERIODO.FIN
AND TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TB.KLKCLBOSE'
```

Trazendo uma linha somente com o resultado de

```
'SELECT TR.CODPARC, TR.NOMEPARC, TB.CODVEND, TV.APELIDO, TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP'
```

Que serão exatamente iguais e a soma dos campos `TP.AD_CAMPLENTE, TP.AD_CAMPPONTOS` na mesma linha.

Comment: Para a gente te ajudar de forma mais rápida, coloque um exemplo de entrada de dados http://sqlfiddle.com/ e a saída esperada aqui na pergunta.

Comment: faz group by desses campos

Comment: Fazendo group by de TR.CODPARC, TR.NOMEPARC, TB.CODVEND, TV.APELIDO, TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP diz que não é uma operação group by e botando distinct não aceita o select.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o que deseja, e que tentaram explicar nos comentários, é:

```
SELECT TR.CODPARC, TR.NOMEPARC, TB.CODVEND, TV.APELIDO, TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP, SUM(TP.AD_CAMPLENTE), SUM(TP.AD_CAMPPONTOS)
FROM TGFCAB TB, TGFITE TE, TGFPRO TP, TGFPAR TR, TGFVEN TV
Where Tb.Nunota = Te.Nunota 
AND TB.CODVEND = TV.CODVEND
AND TP.CODPROD = TE.CODPROD
AND TB.CODPARC = TR.CODPARC
And Tb.Tipmov = 'P'
AND TB.CODTIPOPER IN (3100, 3102, 3105)
AND TB.DTNEG >= :PERIODO.INI
AND TB.DTNEG <= :PERIODO.FIN
AND TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TR.CODPARC, TR.NOMEPARC, TB.CODVEND, TV.APELIDO, TV.AD_CARTAOCAMP
ORDER BY TB.KLKCLBOSE'
```

Comment: Ao usar essa query ocorre o seguinte erro : "ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY"